# Why does removing the / from the end of URL give me a 403?

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-403

Hello I recently coded a storefront child theme on Wordpress on my localhost and used the Free Version of Duplicator to move it to my website's server for demo.  The website works fine at this url: http://connorperzely.com/advancedpowereq.com/

However, when I try to load it at the same URL without the trailing "/" it returns a 403: http://connorperzely.com/advancedpowereq.com

Why does the 403 occur when the / is removed from the end of the url?  And how can I fix it so it will work as normal?

Here's my .htaccess:

```
# This file was updated by Duplicator on 2017-08-18 23:29:51. See .htaccess.orig for the original .htaccess file.
# Please note that other plugins and resources write to this file. If the time-stamp above is different
# than the current time-stamp on the file system then another resource has updated this file.
# Duplicator only writes to this file once during the install process while running the installer.php file.

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /advancedpowereq.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /advancedpowereq.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: in wordpress you need to change `base_url` and `home_url` through your admin panel

Comment: Free support for the [Duplicator plugin here](https://snapcreek.com/duplicator/docs/faqs-tech?utm_source=duplicator_free&utm_medium=wp_org&utm_content=faq_support&utm_campaign=duplicator_free#faq-resource-030-q). [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Comment: @AlivetoDie they both represent the same thing: http://i.imgur.com/rbPLd6V.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as expected according to your .htaccess file.

The url: http://connorperzely.com/advancedpowereq.com ending id .com therefore it is recognized as a file and the line 
`RewriteRule . /advancedpowereq.com/index.php [L]` is not reached.

It is not recomended to have a dot in your subdomain, and `http://connorperzely/advancedpowereq` will work fluently

Comment: This works, thank you!  Set it up again at http://connorperzely.com/advancedpowereq and it loads without the 403.